# Is there a preconfigure time out for spring boot WebClient (webflux) for block() request?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, webclient

I saw somewhere that spring web client will wait 30 seconds by default till it able to establish
a connection. this sound resonable so I just use the default.

However, I have api call using web client with block() that it is actually require to wait
the called service to finish a task before sending a response, currently I just
intruduce Thread.sleep(2 minutes) and the calling service seems to wait which is good but I need
to know how it is configure, I need to make sure the data will be process in full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no default timeout configured for block and its blocked indefinitely until next its resolved.

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#block--

There are alternate methods like with timeout to specify the timeout in Spring WebFlux

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#block-java.time.Duration-

Comment: thanks, it's look like there is no default, so if leave the block() as is, it will be work even if it takes 10m to complete/

Comment: yes it will take 10 m